# Difference between ZIP and ZIP2

Tags: r, gamlss

I am wondering about the difference between ZIP and ZIP2 distributions in the `gamlss` package.

I read, in the gamlss documentation, that

> The ZIP2 is a different parameterization of the ZIP distribution. In the ZIP2 the mu is the mean of the distribution.

I found in the documentation that for ZIP, sigma is the probability at zero, but what is mu?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's more details in the [freely available older version](https://www.gamlss.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/06/DistributionsForModellingLocationScaleandShape-1.pdf) of the `gamlss` book (section 18.2.11-12). The regular Poisson model is parametrized through a mean $\mu$, the zero-inflated version adds $\sigma=P(0)$. This means that in ZIP your $\mu$ will be the mean *of the Poisson component* (i.e. not including excess zeroes), the overall mean is $\mu\ (1-\sigma)$.

ZIP2 reparametrizes the Poisson mean as $\mu/(1-\sigma)$, so $\mu$ is now the grand mean including excess zeroes.